# IHostedService doesn't work when published

Tags: c#, service, jobs

I have simple job in my application to get some items every night.
I'm using IHostedService:

```cs
public class ItemsService : IHostedService
{
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {            
        // code...
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // code ...
    }
}
```

And I registered this service in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // code....
        services.AddHostedService<ItemsService>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // code...
    }
}
```

While running app locally this job works, when I publish app on server it doesn't. I tried to restart app on server but still nothing